# why my pagination code is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

This is my pagination function under which pagination code is written and i have called this pagination function(abc(offset=0)) in another function login_process in else if part, and passed abc function value to view admin_view inside the function login_process and in my login_view i have used pagination code and in that fetched data is shown with pagination but when i click the link 1 2 or any then comes error The requested URL /terse/welcome/abc/1 was not found on this server.and pagination is not implimented 
my pagination function code:

```
public function abc($offset = 0){

    $this->load->model('insert_model');
     //$data ['query'] = $this->insert_model->view_data(); 
    $this->load->library('table');

    // Load Pagination
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    // Config setup
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'/welcome/abc';
$items= $config['total_rows'] = 20;
    $perpage=$config['per_page'] = 1;
    // I added this extra one to control the number of links to show up at each page.
    $config['num_links'] = 5;

    // Initialize
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    // Query the database and get results
    // Here we add the limit and the offset
    // The second parameter is the limit, since we are showing
    // 10 per page, the limit should be 10
    $data['books'] = $this->db->get('register',5, $offset);

    // Create custom headers
    $header = array('id','username','lastname','email' , 'password', 'image','status');
    // Set the headings
    $this->table->set_heading($header);
    // Load the view and send the results
    return $data['books'];

}
```

my login_process function in which i have called abc and passed its value to admin_view(only see its elseif part)

```
 public function login_process()
    {
        $this->load->model('insert_model');
        $data['users'] = array(
                            'fname' => $this->input->post('fname'),

                            'pass'=> $this->input->post('pass'),

                           ); 


        $status= $this->insert_model->login_test($data);
        $st['ss']=$this->insert_model->stat($data); 
        //print "<pre>"; print_r($status); die();
        if($status == true && $st['ss'] [0] ['status'] == 0)
        {
            $ses = array(
                        'username' =>  $this->input->post('fname'),
                        'password' =>  $this->input->post('pass'),
                );

             $this->session->set_userdata($ses);
             $im['pic']=$this->insert_model->image_fetc();

             $this->load->view('header_view',$im);
             $this->load->view('navside_view');
             $this->load->view('user_view');

        }
        elseif($status == true && $st['ss']['0'] ['status'] == 1)
        {
            $ses = array(
                        'username' =>  $this->input->post('fname'),
                        'password' =>  $this->input->post('pass'),
                );

             $this->session->set_userdata($ses);
             $im['pic']=$this->insert_model->image_fetc();


            // print_r($aaa); die();
            //  $data['aa'] = "sd";     
            $data['books'] = $this->abc();
             $this->load->view('header_view',$im);
             $this->load->view('navside_view');
             $this->load->view('admin_view', $data);
        }
        else
            {

                $this->load->view('header_view');
             $this->load->view('navside_view');
             $this->load->view('center_view_login');
            }

}
```

my admin_view code

```
  echo $this->table->generate($books); ?>
    <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
```

please check what i have done wrong..

Comment: is there no one who can solve this

Comment: Instead of $data['books'] = $this->db->get('register',5, $offset); Try : function fetch_books($offset) { $this->db->limit(5,$offset); $query = $this->db->get("register"); if ($query->num_rows() > 0) { foreach ($query->result() as $row) { $data[] = $row; } return $data; } return false; }

$data['books']=fetch_books($offset);

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it was solved when I added the path to the controller function in my appplication/config/routes.php file
something similar to:

```html
$route['terse/welcome/abc/(:num)'] = 'terse/welcome/abc';
```

Customize it. Hope it helps you.